# rd "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents" how it work?

Tags: command-line, window, documents, user-folders, special-locations

I use the following commands:

```
rd "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents"
mklink /J "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents" "D:\Save Games\Documents"
```

and it does not work. I've tried search engines but failed (sorry my English is bad)

Comment: If you want to relocate your documents folder, just right-click it in explorer, open properties, go to the location tab and enter your new part. No need to deal with cmd and junctions.

Comment: but i doing for a lot of computer, i need a command line, thank for reply

Answer (score 0):

after time used to search engines I found the following command:

```
reg.exe add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Personal /t REG_SZ /d "D:\Save Games\Documents" /f
```

thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

rd "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents"
mklink /J "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents" "D:\Save Games\Documents" Instagram

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).